# Any material randomly turning into emission in Cycles, in blender 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, emission

The file I'm working on just glitched out. In Eevee, we can see what it is supposed to look like, but as soon as I switch to Cycles, every material seemingly turns into an emission shader material. This happened before with another file, but in this one it affected every material and it happened randomly. Reassigning the material or a new material doesn't help. it simply turns into an emitter, even though the emission tab in the principled BSDF is completely black.

[image]

I have some more pictures:
1. Eevee rendered view, all lights in the scene visible
[image]

2. Eevee rendered view, lights off (all but one)
   [image]
3. Cycles rendered view, all lights in the scene off. Normal material turns emissive[image]

The only thing I changed between numbers 2 and 3 is changing from Eevee to Cycles (and hiding the other point light). Both are in the rendered viewport shading mode.

Comment: Hard to guess with the provided information. It seems to me that what changed is the intensity of the lights. But the images provided are not enough to understand the scene. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post and add more information.

Comment: Please check that your base color has values within range [0,1].

Comment: I guess because you are in shading mode, the materials are showed based on the material view and not render view

Comment: @fourtwo Being in the shading tab, doesn't affect the viewport render, normally. Even if I go to another tab, the problem still persists.

Comment: @RobertGützkow what do you mean? the base color for the plane is #0092E7, yet it still looks like an emission shader...

Comment: I meant the values in the RGB tab of the color picker. If these are above 1.0 you can get strange effects. I'm not sure how the hex values would be displayed in that case. Please also check if AO is enabled or if the scene light or scene world option have been disabled (*Viewport Shading*).

Comment: @RobertGützkow It was AO! When I am in Cycles and turn go to view layer -> filter -> AO and turn it off, the problem disappears. Thank you so much!